# How to create a sequence of variables and store them in lists while a given condition is not met?

Tags: python, python-3.x, list, while-loop

I'm trying to make a program that reads and executes the following conditions, how could I do that?

```
while condition not met: 

a1,b1,c1 = map(str, input().split())

a2,b2,c2 = map(str, input().split())

a3,b3,c3 = map(str, input().split())
...

...

...
a1, a2, a3 stored in list1[]

b1, b2, b3 stored in list2[]

c1, c2, c3 stored in list3[]
```

Comment: Please explain how is your question related to tag `[python-requests]` which you did use?

Comment: Add what you've tried and hasn't worked: I can't see any *question* here.  Incidentally `map(str, input().split()` does absolutely nothing more than `input().split()`.  What are you trying to do more generally?  And what does this have to do with `python-requests`?

Comment: I wasn't quite accuracte: `map(str, input.split()` does indeed do something---it wastes cpu cycles casting strs to strs.  But the output of input.split() is *already* a list of strings

Comment: `input` is returning strings, so no need to convert again: `map(str, input().split())
` -> `input().split()`
`

Comment: a3,b2,c3 : should this be a3, b**3**,c3?

Comment: Complete shot in the dark: do you know how many lists you will have in advance?  Is the question something like 'read until a condition is met whilst appending answers and then return all those answers?'  It would *really* help to have a use-case and some idea what yuo're trying to do here

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Bad Approach

```
list = [][]
while condition not met:
a, b, c = map(str, input().split())
list[0].append(a)
list[1].append(b)
list[2].append(c)
```

`a1, a2, a3 ...` will be stored in `list[0]`

`b1, b2, b3 ...` will be stored in `list[1]`

`c1, c2, c3 ...` will be stored in `list[2]`